# Snowflake - How can I execute an EXECUTE IMMMEDIATE with a concat

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

The goal would be to generate a different query based on a list of table values and execute the generated query. There are 3 places where there is a loop to do: in the FROM and in the 2 LEFT JOIN

The list of values is: 'TOP1' and 'TOP2'. So it would be the same request but changing the end of it

```
FROM THE_TOP1_ATP A
LEFT JOIN THE_TOP1_WTA B
LEFT JOIN THE_TOP1_WTA C
```

and its alternative :

```
FROM THE_TOP2_ATP A
LEFT JOIN THE_TOP2_WTA B
LEFT JOIN THE_TOP2_WTA C
```

Currently, my query generates the same modified query but does not execute it (because it contains aggregations and is not a single continuous string so it's stuck at the first concatenation and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE does not work). Here is the said request :

```
SELECT LISTAGG('SELECT
A."LASTNAME" AS "Player Name",
A."FIRSTNAME" AS "Player Firstname",
B."SOCDATA" AS "Metadata"
FROM THE_' || f.value || '_ATP A
LEFT JOIN THE_' || f.value || '_WTA B
LEFT JOIN THE_' || f.value || '_WTA C') FROM TABLE(flatten(input => array_construct('TOP1','TOP2'))) f;
```

The output needs to be generated (SnowFlake) and run, not manually.

Not possible obviously with an EXECUTE IMMEDIATE...

Thanks for your help guys !

Comment: Has anyone ever had this problem with SnowFlake?

Comment: I think you need to explain your problem better. “a loop over tables” is not a phrase that means anything to me and I’ve been using SQL for 20+ years.   Posting DDL might help a bit. Probably to delete your question and try again with more clarity.

Comment: Sorry if there is not enough details. By “a loop over tables” I meant : I have a list of values containing "TOP1" and "TOP2" and I'd like to create the same sql statement but twice (one finishing by "FROM I_TOP1_ATP A" and the other by "FROM I_TOP2_ATP A" - same for the 2 following LEFT JOIN)

Comment: Not sure that helps. “a list of values” is not really SQL thing (maybe unless your are talking about an IN list). Better to talk about tables and columns. DDL helps

Comment: if you have some SQL you want to generate and run you will want to use Snowflake Scripting, I just answered a another question, that does this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73955266/43992