# Snowflake Split Columns at delimiter to Multiple Columns

Tags: split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table as below

[image]

I want to split the column OWNERS at delimiter ',' and create new columns.
No of columns to be created depends on owners in OWNERS column. There is no MAX count for names in OWNERS column.
Expected result is as below .

Requesting help

[image]

Comment: SPLIT_TO_TABLE() or SPLIT() functions can be used here, but you'd then need to PIVOT the table to get them into columns, which requires that you know how many owner columns that are needed based on the data.

Comment: @MikeWalton : I tried split didnt work . It created an array but was not able to get the array into seperate columns   [
  "Benson",
  " James",
  "Walters",
  " Shae",
  "Greene",
  " Lacy"
]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data:

```
create table table_a as
select * from values
  ('L1','Benson,Greene,Lacy'),
  ('L2','Walter,Amson'),
  ('L3','Rustin'),
  ('L4','Thomas,Justin,Greene,Lacy')
;
```

hand sql as per Dave's answer:

```
select
  column1 as lease,
  nullif(split_part(column2,',',1),'') owner1,
  nullif(split_part(column2,',',2),'') owner2,
  nullif(split_part(column2,',',3),'') owner3,
  nullif(split_part(column2,',',4),'') owner4
from table_a;
```

the max number is:

```
select max(array_size(split(column2,','))) from table_a;
```

| MAX(ARRAY_SIZE(SPLIT(COLUMN2,','))) |
| --- |
| 4 |

so lets make the first SQL dynamically:

```
declare
  sql text;
  maximum_count integer;
begin
  select max(array_size(split(column2,','))) into :maximum_count from table_a;
  sql := 'select column1 as lease';
  
  for i in 1 to maximum_count do
    sql := sql || ' ,nullif(split_part(column2,'','','|| i ||'),'''') owner'||i;
  end for;
  sql := sql || ' from table_a;';
  return sql;
end;
```

| anonymous block |
| --- |
| select column1 as lease ,nullif(split_part(column2,',',1),'') owner1 ,nullif(split_part(column2,',',2),'') owner2 ,nullif(split_part(column2,',',3),'') owner3 ,nullif(split_part(column2,',',4),'') owner4 from table_a; |

so now lets call that and return those results:

```
declare
  sql text;
  maximum_count integer;
  res resultset;
begin
  select max(array_size(split(column2,','))) into :maximum_count from table_a;
  sql := 'select column1 as lease';
  
  for i in 1 to maximum_count do
    sql := sql || ' ,nullif(split_part(column2,'','','|| i ||'),'''') owner'||i;
  end for;
  sql := sql || ' from table_a;';
  
  res := (execute immediate :sql);
  return table (res);
end;
```

if you are still running in the old UI:

```
execute immediate $$
declare
  sql text;
  maximum_count integer;
  res resultset;
begin
  select max(array_size(split(column2,','))) into :maximum_count from test.public.table_a;
  sql := 'select column1 as lease';
  
  for i in 1 to maximum_count do
    sql := sql || ' ,nullif(split_part(column2,'','','|| i ||'),'''') owner'||i;
  end for;
  sql := sql || ' from table_a;';
  
  res := (execute immediate :sql);
  return table (res);
end;
$$
;
```

Comment: Simeon when I run above query all together it is giving error message -                         
  SQL compilation error: syntax error line 2 at position 11 unexpected '<EOF>'.

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples.html

Comment: @SimeonPilgrim, How can you make the results in the above answer into a table?

Answer (score 0):

This works for 4 owners. For an unlimited number of owners, you will probably need to build the SQL string interactively and then EXECUTE IMMEDIATE.

Source: [Pivot ANYTHING in Snowflake, Without the SQL PIVOT Function](https://medium.com/snowflake/pivot-anything-in-snowflake-without-the-sql-pivot-function-ba030dce8dfc) which includes information about the pivot option.

```
with t(lease,owners) as (
  select * from values
  ('L1','Benson,Greene,Lacy'),
  ('L2','Walter,Amson'),
  ('L3','Rustin'),
  ('L4','Thomas,Justin,Greene,Lacy')
)
select
  lease,
  iff(split_part(owners,',',1)<>'',split_part(owners,',',1),'') owner1,
  iff(split_part(owners,',',2)<>'',split_part(owners,',',2),'') owner2,
  iff(split_part(owners,',',3)<>'',split_part(owners,',',3),'') owner3,
  iff(split_part(owners,',',4)<>'',split_part(owners,',',4),'') owner4
from t;
```

| LEASE | OWNER1 | OWNER2 | OWNER3 | OWNER4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| L1 | Benson | Greene | Lacy |  |
| L2 | Walter | Amson |  |  |
| L3 | Rustin |  |  |  |
| L4 | Thomas | Justin | Greene | Lacy |

Comment: the template row can be even simple with NULLIF `nullif(split_part(owners,',',1),'') owner1`