# Split one value into multiple columns in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying split the one value into multiple columns in Snowflake.

I have data like below.

```
Column1 
A;BC;D;E;FGH;IJ;K;L;MN;OPQR;
```

And I want to split into multiple columns like below

```
Column1 Column2 Column3  Column4  Column5  Column6  Column7  Column8  Column9  Column10 
A        BC     D          E        FGH     IJ        K       L        MN       OPQR
```

Please help me to achieve this.
Thanks in Advance.

I'm using `substr(column1,1,CHARINDEX(';',column1,1))`, but getting only one value. I'm not sure how to get the remaining values.

Appreciate your inputs.

Comment: You can use SPLIT function. That will return an array. Then you can use FLATTEN on that array to get all values as rows. After all you can transpose the table so that you can have every row as column

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to split a comma-separated value to columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10581772/how-to-split-a-comma-separated-value-to-columns)

Comment: For an arbitrary number of columns?

Comment: See [Snowflake split columns at delimiter to multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73953678/snowflake-split-columns-at-delimiter-to-multiple-columns)

Answer (score 0):

if the number of columns are fixed then you can try something as follows.

```
SELECT arr[0] AS col1,  arr[1] AS col2, arr[2] AS col3 ,
arr[3] AS col4,  arr[4] AS col5, arr[5] AS col6 ,
arr[6] AS col7,  arr[7] AS col8, arr[8] AS col9, arr[9] AS col10, arr FROM (
select split('A;BC;D;E;FGH;IJ;K;L;MN;OPQR;', ';') arr );
```